# Revert to original html after pressing Esc button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I modified an html thru javascript and I want that when I click esc, it will go back to the html's original form:

```
if ($("#div").show()) {
    $("#div1").empty();
    $("#div1").html("<input class='tabledit-input form-control' type='text' value='" + file[0].name + "'>");

    $("#div2").empty();
    $("#div2").html("<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='div2'>");

    $("#div3").empty();
    $("#div3").html("<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='div3'>");
} else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    //what to do here?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.clone()` method to have a clone of the original ones before the event happens:

```
//#################  clone them here ######################

var d1 = $("#div1").clone(),
    d2 = $("#div2").clone(),
    d3 = $("#div3").clone();
```

Now in the event, you can replace them with:

```
if ($("#div").show()) {
    $("#div1").empty();
    $("#div1").html("<input class='tabledit-input form-control' type='text' value='" + file[0].name + "'>");

    $("#div2").empty();
    $("#div2").html("<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='div2'>");

    $("#div3").empty();
    $("#div3").html("<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='div3'>");
} else if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    //################# now replace it here. ####################
    $('#div1').replaceWith(d1);
    $('#div2').replaceWith(d2);
    $('#div3').replaceWith(d3);
}
```